# MySQL Denormalization / Optimisation - MAX(Value)

Tags: mysql, sql

**Data in Log Table**

| id | type | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | in | 2022-01-10 |
| 2 | in | 2022-01-10 |
| 3 | out | 2022-01-10 |
| 4 | out | 2022-01-10 |
| 5 | out | 2022-01-11 |
| 6 | in | 2022-01-12 |
| 7 | in | 2022-01-12 |
| 8 | out | 2022-01-12 |
| 9 | out | 2022-01-12 |

**Expected Result**

| id | type | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | in | 2022-01-12 |
| 7 | in | 2022-01-12 |

Query that I am running now:

```
SELECT * FROM table_log WHERE type = 'in' AND created_date = (SELECT MAX(created_date) FROM table_log WHERE type = 'in')
```

For instance, I am trying to get data which has type as "in" with latest created_date. My query is working fine but I am wondering if there's anyway I can improve because it running 2 same query.

Comment: *Query that I am running now* The query is optimal enough. Create according index `(type, created_date)` for its improvement simply. *it running 2 same query.* They're not "the same".

Comment: There are several different approaches to the same problem in the answers to the linked duplicate question. Compare the speed of the various approaches and select the one that works the best for you.